# AWS SDK function is not being called when run used on a lambda function deployed by Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-amplify

I'm trying to add a user to a group in my Amplify project programatically. I created a lambda function as shown below and deployed it using amplify functions. I setup the permissions to the functions's role following this article: https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/aws-amplify-adding-user-group-programmatically-guillermo-misa-iii. The function get's executed. No errors. It doesn't even run the console log which means the callback is not being called. The user is not being added to the group either. There's no error logs in the lambda function logs. Any idea what's happening?

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    const cognitoIdentityServiceProvider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

    cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminAddUserToGroup({
        GroupName: 'abcd', //your confirmed user gets added to this group
        UserPoolId: event.arguments.userPoolId,
        Username: event.arguments.userName
    }, function(err, data) {
        console.log('Ran the function')

        if (err) {
            callback(err) // uh oh, an error
        }

        callback(null, event); // yay! success
    })

    // return response;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the guide I followed, they have used a normal function as the lambda handler:

```js
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {})
```

But I have used an `async` function:

```js
exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {})
```

It seems in an `async` function, lambda does not wait till the callback is called. It expects us to use the `async` `await` syntax in our code. So, I have to convert the function like this:

```js
try {
    await cognitoIdentityServiceProvider.adminAddUserToGroup({
        GroupName: 'abcd', //your confirmed user gets added to this group
        UserPoolId: event.arguments.userPoolId,
        Username: event.arguments.userName
    }).promise()

    callback(null, event); // yay! success
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
}
```

Now everything works! **Notice** that we can get a promise out of `aws-sdk` functions if we call `.promise()`.